# changing the value of one combobox causes the value of the other one changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am two Combobox which are populated with a view of a table like following

```
  recieverComboBox.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView; 
  recieverComboBox.DisplayMember = "UserPosition";
  recieverComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";

  recieverUnReadComboBox.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
  recieverUnReadComboBox.DisplayMember = "UserPosition";
  recieverUnReadComboBox.ValueMember = "usr_Id";
```

when I change the value of each of them, the value of the other one changes automatically. why is that ?

Comment: Do you have any event handler written for selectedindexchanged event?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: Yes I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to avoid this issue.

**Solution A：**

Use BindingSource as the DataSource of ComboBox.

```
recieverComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView, null);
recieverComboBox.DisplayMember = "UserPosition";
recieverComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";

recieverUnReadComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView, null);
recieverUnReadComboBox.DisplayMember = "UserPosition";
recieverUnReadComboBox.ValueMember = "usr_Id";
```

---

**Solution B:**

Call method [`DataTable.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.copy?view=netcore-3.1)

```
recieverComboBox.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0].Copy();
recieverComboBox.DisplayMember = "UserPosition";
recieverComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";

recieverUnReadComboBox.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0].Copy();
recieverUnReadComboBox.DisplayMember = "UserPosition";
recieverUnReadComboBox.ValueMember = "usr_Id";
```